# Confusion about functional derivative in path integral

Tags: propagator, functional-derivatives

> If we act a functional derivative $$\frac{\delta}{\delta J(z)}$$On the expression$$\int\int d^4x d^4y \space J(x)\Delta(x-y)J(y)$$
>   where $\Delta(x-y)$ is Feynman propagator.
>   What one should get is
>   $$2\int d^4y\Delta(z-y)J(y).$$

But what I get is
$$\int d^4xd^4y\space\delta(x-z)\Delta(x-y)J(y)+ \int d^4xd^4yJ(x)\Delta(x-y)\delta(y-z).$$
After calculating delta function and change of variable, this is equivalent as:
$$\int d^4y\Delta(z-y)J(y)+\int d^4y\Delta(y-z)J(y).$$

Is Feynman propagator "even"? How do i get the correct result?

If it's even, how do we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second equation you quote, only the symmetric $x\leftrightarrow y$ part contributes, so you may as well assume that $\Delta(x-y)=\Delta(y-x)$.

In other words 
$$
\Delta(x-y) =\frac 12 (\Delta(x-y)+\Delta(y-x))+ \frac 1 2(\Delta(x-y)-\Delta(y-x))
$$
and 
$$
\frac 12 \int d^nx d^ny J(x) \{\Delta(x-y)-\Delta(y-x)\}J(y)=0.
$$

Comment: It seems like one cannot switch x and y in Feynman propagator with out changing the value of it. Can you prove it?

Comment: Im not saying that $\Delta(x-y)= \Delta(y-x)$. What I am saying is that only the symmetric part contributes. I will edit my answer say this more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The Feynman propagator of a scalar particle is even. Proof:
$$
\Delta(x-y) = \int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{e^{-i(x-y)\cdot p}}{p^2-m^2+i \varepsilon}\,.
$$
Changing variable to $p^\mu = - q^\mu$ (the Jacobian is $1$) is equivalent to send $x-y \to y-x$ .